# Coding conventions and standards

Tags: c#, attributes, hardcoded

Can anyone tell if the values written in attributes are considered as hardcoded values.

For example **customerId** written in **JsonProperty**

```
{
        [JsonProperty("customerId")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("phoneNumber")]
        public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Of course they are hardcoded values. Why is that a bad thing in this case?

Comment: What's the use case? If you load the values at startup from a file into the attributes they are IMHO not hard coded. If you fill them from a constant string they are. It doesn't depend on the attribute itself.

Comment: @Markus How could you do that? Attributes are constant values. The only way you could maybe do it is if you had something to inject them at compile time.

Comment: In c#, an attribute is part of the type, just like the method and property names, interfaces, access modifiers, and everything else that makes up a type. Would you consider your method names "hardcoded"?

Comment: Aww crap, my brain seemingly was on "pause".  Imixed up the attribute and property :/ These are of course hard coded.

Comment: @John if they are considered as hardcoded values than do I need to store these values in constant class.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, what is the problem with the class declaration you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in an attribute, they need to be constants and cannot be variables. I have not come across any coding guide that has said this should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Constant file contains string constants that are frequently used and hence we replace those constants such that if at a later point we have to change it then we only have to change at one location (Constant Class) and not at multiple locations however in your case the attributes have hard coded values but unless these exact values are used in multiple places i don't really see any concern or any need to put these under a constant class file, its just one of the reasons why we maintain a constant class in the first place, and yes there are a few more reasons, however i don't see any problem with the above approach.